# Make zsh completion more bash-like / best practice with zsh completion

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, zsh-completion

Using bash I did like to do something like this:

```
$ l
file15165
file23132
file31351
xyzfile
$ $CMD f<TAB>
(f gets completed to "file", I type "*", [23] or whatever)
$ $CMD file*<Enter>
```

This way I am sure the command is executed on all the files I want it to.

When I try to do this with zsh, this happens:

```
$ l
file15165
file23132
file31351
xyzfile
$ $CMD f<TAB>
(f is completed to "file15165", I have to press <backspace> five times and then type "*")
$ $CMD file*<Enter>
```

Which is quite ineffective. Now how can I achieve the bash behaviour using zsh? Or how would a zsh user attempt to do what I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I had `setopt menucomplete` in my .zshrc, which resulted in the explained behaviour. Removing it fixed it.